# I am trying for a tar call and getting the below error

Tags: command-line, tar, archive

I am trying to use tar and get the following error:

```
$ tar --strip-components=1 xf /data/rvm-latest.tar.gz 
tar: You must specify one of the `-Acdtrux' or `--test-label' options
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
```

Answer (score 3):

That means that one of those options (-Acdtrux) needs to come first on the command line, before other options.

So, try:

```
tar x --strip-components=1 -f /data/rvm-latest.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

Long options must come after short options when using *traditional style*.

Instead of

```
tar --strip-components=1 xf /data/rvm-latest.tar.gz
```

use

```
tar xf /data/rvm-latest.tar.gz --strip-components=1
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not using `tar` but rather `gtar`.

....and you are using a mix of the standard `tar` commandline syntax and vendor specific extensions.

Given that `tar` does not like a `-` in front of the `key letters` and the fact that the `key letters` must come first, the only way to enhance the tar syntax is to disallow extensions to appear before the key letters.

If you use the elements from the official tar syntax first, things will work:

`gtar xf /data/rvm-latest.tar.gz -other-non-tar-extensions`.

Comment: It's not `gtar` on his system, it's `tar` - don't impose your weird binary-naming foibles on his system.  That `tar` happens to be GNU tar and GNU tar supports some options that other versions of tar do not, just as other versions of tar support some options that GNU tar doesn't.  Finally, given that even you managed to deduce that it was GNU tar from the options being used, there's no point in complaining about the OP asking about a GNU tar problem.  BTW, please don't resist your vindictive urge to downvote my answer for failing to hate on GNU or Linux, i really don't care.

Comment: The main problem on most Linux distros is that `gtar` is not installed under it's native name but only as `tar`. This is what usually causes confusion and what you still do not seem to understand.

Comment: What you refuse to understand is that this is not a bug, it is a feature.  or simply a fact if you can't bring yourself to tolerate the word 'feature'.  GNU tar **IS** the native tar on Linux systems.  GNU tools **ARE** the standard, default userland on GNU/Linux so there is no need for your silly g-prefix for GNU commands.

Comment: Well, it seems tat you are not a sysadmin that likes to be able to write portable scripts. If you like to use a vendor specific tool on more than a single platform, you need to call it under it's native name.

Comment: tar IS its native name on GNU/Linux.  on GNU/Linux there is no such binary as `gtar`.  writing scripts expecting `gtar` to exist is non-portable and will break.  It is, in fact, you who are non-portable by insisting that what is true on your idiosyncratically-configured solaris system (probably one of the very few remaining in the world) is true on every non-solaris system in the world, including Linux systems.

Comment: It seems that you live in your own world and that there is no hope this may change as your statements seem to be hate origined.